# ETL Transformation of Generic Transaction into Bet and Win

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I've got a problem in my database, understanding a generic Transaction if its a Bet or Win. Currently it consists both in one transaction. 
I've an additional field which can help -> Bet Amount, which is constant.

Here is how the table looks like:

[image]

Basically what you see in Amount Field in the first transaction, is the Amount the customer starts with. Whenever the amount of next transactions are higher compare to its previous transaction then the specific Bet has got a Win too, if its lower then its only a Bet.

My need is to create an ETL process which will Create this Table:

[image]

Hope you can help me write an efficient SQL Server code in order to create the requested Table.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Use the script below as SQL Command in your OLEDB Source

```
SELECT TransactionID, DateTime, GameID, CASE WHEN ISNULL(Amount, '') = '' THEN 
'StartGame' WHEN Amount > BetAmount THEN 'win' ELSE 'bet' END AS 
TransactionTypeID, BetAmount, Amount
FROM [your table name]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'd try to do this purely in SSIS, but here's a query that *should* do the right thing:

```
select *, 
   case 
      when LAG(Amount, 1, Amount) over (order by TransactionID) = Amount then 'Bet' 
      else 'Win' 
   end
from dbo.Transactions;
```

I'm using the `LAG()` function to look back one row at the value for the `Amount` column in the previous row (where "previous" is defined by the ordering of TransactionID†). If that value is the same, consider it a Bet otherwise it's a Win.

†  It seems like you'd want to consider games in isolation. If that's the case, change the `OVER()` clause on the `LAG()` function to `partition by GameID order by TransactionID`.